# C# Save XLS to CSV: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, csv

**System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

How to solve this error ?

Can anyone know this ?

Below my coding... when execute it produce the error that

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException Index was outside the bounds of the array

, only if tried to process this csv file :

[image]

Instead I don't have error if tried to process this csv file :
[image]

```
Excel.IExcelDataReader excelReader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
excelReader.Close();
result.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();
string csvData = "";
int row_no = 0;
int ind = 0;

while (row_no < result.Tables[ind].Rows.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[ind].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        csvData += result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + "|";
    }

    row_no++;
    csvData += "\n";
}

keys = GetUniqueKey(12).ToUpper();
output = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/public/" + keys.ToString() + ".csv");
StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false);
csv.Write(csvData);
csv.Close();
csv.Dispose();

string toCheck;
using (var fs = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default))
{
    toCheck = sr.ReadToEnd();
    if (toCheck.Contains("ColumnAAA") == false)
    {
        ////Start add new column
        int posNewColumn = 2;
        string[] CSVDump = File.ReadAllLines(output);
        List<List<string>> CSV = CSVDump.Select(x => x.Split('|').ToList()).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < CSV.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CSV[i].Count > posNewColumn)
            {
                CSV[i].Insert(posNewColumn, i == 0 ? "ColumnAAA" : "ColumnAAA");
            }
            else
            {
                CSV[i].Add(i == 0 ? "ColumnAAA" : "ColumnAAA");
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(output, CSV.Select(x => string.Join("|", x)));
        sr.Close();
        ////End add new column
    }
}
```

**Edit #01**

The problem is in this line of code-behind.

The code print correctly the number of rows, but I have error when try print and Split the number of columns  :

```
lines = File.ReadAllLines(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/public/" + keys.ToString() + ".csv"));
rows = lines.Count();
columns = lines[23].Split('|').Count();

Response.Write("Number of rows/columns = " + rows.ToString() + "/" + columns.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger? I'd recommend to find the line of your code where this error happens. After this it will be much easier to fix the problem.

Comment: @Ilya Thank you for reply, please see **Edit #01** in my first question-

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
lines = File.ReadAllLines(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/public/" + keys.ToString() + ".csv"));
rows = lines.Count();

int i = 0;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split('|');
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        columns = parts.Count();
    }
    i++;
}

Response.Write("Number of rows/columns = " + rows.ToString() + "/" + columns.ToString());
Response.End();
```